# Zend PDO - no primary key in view

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo

I'm getting this exception:

```
Message: A table must have a primary key, but none was found
```

When trying to execute the following code on a view:

$tbl = new Zend_Db_Table(array('name'=>'attribute_map'));

```
$row = $tbl->fetchRow(
    $tbl->select()
        ->where('attribute_code = 7')
);
```

MySQL doesn't have indexed views. As such, they can't have primary keys. How do I get around this? Do I really need to execute a standalone query? Why can't Zend identify a view?